# How To incorporate TurboParser Instead of MaltParser for improved results like from online demo?

Tags: computational-linguistics

I have successfully installed Semafor on Linux Mint 18.1 and I can run it. But the results I get from my version differs drastically from the online demo. I realized that online demo uses TurboParser, not MaltPraser. I tried A LOT to download TurboParser's model, but the remote host is sending data on 100 KB/s which is so lousy while I can download from other web sites at about 1 MB/s! But I kept on downloading and finally received a corrupted file. Now I have a request and a question:

1. Can any one upload the model on a better host? Maybe a Google drive or so?
2. How can TurboParser be incorporated in Semafor? I could not figure it out because I failed to download the model.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about programming/getting some webservice to work and not about linguistics. It may be fitting to some other site of the stackexchange network, probably https://stackexchange.com is the first choice.

Comment: Thank you @jknappen! I moved the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190589/how-to-incorporate-turboparser-instead-of-maltparser-for-improved-results-like-f).